# Uploading of File seems to be forever!

Tags: php, apache, cakephp-1.2

I have made a program wherein I am able to upload a file. Everything is working fine.
But, when I tried uploading 11mb file, it seems like it is loading forever or sending the file to server forever..

I have already tried setting the upload_max_filesize to 20M.

Any ideas what could be the cause and how to resolve this?

Comment: Please clarify on a few things:

Comment: Speed of your network connection (is it DSL ? If so, upload speed is significantly slower than download speed)

Comment: can you show the code you use ?

Comment: What speed is your connection to the server?

Comment: At least Chromium shows the upload progess in the bottom left corner. Make sure the upload is complete. While the file is transfered the script is not executed and therefore no changes to php or the script will have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The why is almost certainly related to your connection speed.  Unless you're connecting via a LAN to the machine in question you'll in all probability be connecting via a consumer grade broadband connection.  These are pretty much always configured so that download speed is a lot higher than upload speed.  As a consequence, that 20 meg file that takes a minute or so to download will take 10 minutes or more to upload over the same connection.

What can you do about this, other than switching to an enterprise-grade broadband connection?  Not a great deal, those bits will only transfer so fast over the connection you've got and no faster.  What you can do, however, is at least keep the user informed as to how the upload is progressing.  PHP from version 5.2 onwards provides hooks that you can use to monitor the progress of a file upload.  You can use javascript to monitor these hooks and display a progress bar to the user.

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-ajax-file-uploads

Comment: If it really is a pure bandwidth issue, then it's certainly worth looking at TCP Window scaling issues / QOS routing problems.

Answer (score 0):

How long is "forever"? A typical upload speed on consumer broadband is 256 kilobits per second, at which speed an 11 megabyte file will take [over five minutes](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=11+megabytes+/+256+kbps) to upload.

If you are using the [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) web browser, you get an upload progress bar so you can tell if it is working or not.